# Regarding instruction ordering in executions of cache-miss loads before cache-hit stores on x86

Tags: x86, cpu-architecture, memory-model

Given the small program shown below (handcrafted to look the same from a sequential consistency / TSO perspective), and assuming it's being run by a superscalar out-of-order x86 cpu:

```
Load A <-- A in main memory
Load B <-- B is in L2
Store C, 123 <-- C is L1
```

I have a few questions:

1. Assuming a big enough instruction-window, will the three instructions be fetched, decoded, executed at the same time? I assume not, as that would break execution in program order.
2. The 2nd load is going to take longer to fetch A from memory than B. Will the later have to wait until the first is fully executed? Will the fetching of B only start after Load A is fully executed? or until when does it have to wait?
3. Why would the store have to wait for the loads? If yes, will the instruction just wait to be committed in the store buffer until the loads finish or after decoding it will have to sit and wait for the loads?

Thanks

Comment: The front-end is irrelevant.  3 consecutive instructions might well be fetched in the same 16-byte fetch block, and might go through pre-decode and decode in the same cycle as a group.  And (also or instead) issue into the out-of-order back-end as part of a group of 3 or 4 uops.  IDK why you think any of that would cause any potential problem.  (Executing simultaneously doesn't put later instructions *before* earlier ones, it puts them at the *same* time.  That's fine.)

Comment: What about 2) ?

Comment: I'm writing an answer for that part; I only commented to point out the flaw in your assumptions.

Comment: oh, thx! 654321

Comment: Are you assuming an in-order superscalar pipeline like Pentium or Atom?  You never mention out-of-order execution, just superscalar.  Because only in-order pipelines normally execute together a group that decoded together.

Comment: I'm assuming a modern, OoO.

Comment: Ok, good, because the answer I'm working on already has some stuff written correcting that assumption about executing together after decoding together.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Terminology: "instruction-window" normally means out-of-order execution window, over which the CPU can find ILP.  i.e. ROB or RS size.  See [Understanding the impact of lfence on a loop with two long dependency chains, for increasing lengths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51986046/understanding-the-impact-of-lfence-on-a-loop-with-two-long-dependency-chains-fo)

The term for how many instructions can go through the pipeline in a single cycle is pipeline *width*.  e.g. Skylake is 4-wide superscalar out-of-order.  (Parts of its pipeline, like decode, uop-cache fetch, and retirement, are wider than 4 uops, but issue/rename is the narrowest point.)

---

Terminology: "*wait to be committed in the store buffer*" store data + address gets written into the store buffer when a store executes.  It *commits* *from* the store buffer to L1d at any point after retirement, when it's known to be non-speculative.

(In program order, to maintain the TSO memory model of no store reordering.  **A store buffer allows stores to *execute* inside this core out of order but still commit to L1d (and become globally visible) in-order.**  **Executing a store = writing address + data to the store buffer.**)
[Can a speculatively executed CPU branch contain opcodes that access RAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64141366/can-a-speculatively-executed-cpu-branch-contain-opcodes-that-access-ram)
Also [what is a store buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105827/what-is-a-store-buffer) and
[Size of store buffers on Intel hardware? What exactly is a store buffer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54876208/size-of-store-buffers-on-intel-hardware-what-exactly-is-a-store-buffer)

---

**The front-end is irrelevant**.  3 consecutive instructions might well be fetched in the same 16-byte fetch block, and might go through pre-decode and decode in the same cycle as a group.  And (also or instead) issue into the out-of-order back-end as part of a group of 3 or 4 uops.  IDK why you think any of that would cause any potential problem.

The front end (from fetch to issue/rename) processes instructions in program order.  Processing simultaneously doesn't put later instructions *before* earlier ones, it puts them at the *same* time.  And more importantly, it preserves the information of what program order is; that's not lost or discarded because it matters for instructions that depend on the previous one<sup>1</sup>!

There are queues between most pipeline stages, so (for example on Intel Sandybridge) instructions that pre-decode as part of a group of up-to-6 instructions might not hit the decoders as part of the same group of up-to-4 (or more with macro-fusion).  See https://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/3/ for fetch, and the next page for decode.  (And the uop cache.)

---

*Executing* (dispatching uops to execution ports from the out-of-order scheduler) is where ordering matters.  **The out-of-order scheduler has to avoid breaking single threaded code.<sup>2</sup>**

Usually issue/rename is far ahead of execution, unless you're bottlenecked on the front-end.  So there's normally no reason to expect that uops that issued together will execute together.  (For the sake of argument, let's assume that the 2 loads you show do get dispatched for execution in the same cycle, regardless of how they got there via the front-end.)

But anyway, there's no problem here *starting* both loads and the store the same time.  The uop scheduler doesn't know whether a load will hit or miss in L1d.  It just sends 2 load uops to the load execution units in a cycle, and a store-address + store-data uop to those ports.

> 2. [load ordering]

**This is the tricky part.**

As I explained in an answer + comments on [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56050177/cache-coherence-literature-generally-only-refers-store-buffers-but-not-read-buff), modern x86 CPUs will *speculatively* use the L2 hit result from Load B for later instructions, even though the memory model requires that this load happens after Load A.

**But if no other cores write to cache line B before Load A completes, then nothing can tell the difference.**  The Memory-Order Buffer takes care of detecting invalidations of cache lines that were loaded from before earlier loads complete, and doing a memory-order mis-speculation pipeline flush (rollback to retirement state) in the rare case that allowing load re-ordering could change the result.

> 3. Why would the store have to wait for the loads?

**It won't, unless the store-address depends on a load value.**  The uop scheduler will dispatch the store-address and store-data uops to execution units when their inputs are ready.

**It's after the loads in program order, and the store buffer will make it even farther after the loads as far as global memory order is concerned.**  The store buffer won't commit the store data to L1d (making it globally visible) until after the store has retired.  Since it's after the loads, they'll have also retired.

(**Retirement is in-order** to allow precise exceptions, and to make sure no *previous* instructions took an exception or were a mispredicted branch.  In-order retirement allows us to say for sure that an instruction is non-speculative after it retires.)

So yes, this mechanism does ensure that the store can't commit to L1d until after both loads have taken data from memory (via L1d cache which provides a coherent view of memory to all cores).  So this prevents LoadStore reordering (of earlier loads with later stores).

I'm not sure if any weakly-ordered OoO CPUs do LoadStore reordering.  It is possible on in-order CPUs when a cache-miss load comes before a cache-hit store, and the CPU uses scoreboarding to avoid stalling until the load data is actually read from a register, if it still isn't ready.  (LoadStore is a weird one: see also Jeff Preshing's [Memory Barriers Are Like Source Control Operations](https://preshing.com/20120710/memory-barriers-are-like-source-control-operations/)).  Maybe some OoO exec CPUs can also track cache-miss stores post retirement when they're known to be definitely happening, but the data just still hasn't arrived yet.  x86 doesn't do this because it would violate the TSO memory model.

---

**Footnote 1:**  There are some architectures (typically VLIW) where bundles of simultaneous instructions are part of the architecture in a way that's visible to software.  So if software can't fill all 3 slots with instructions that can execute simultaneously, it has to fill them with NOPs.  It might even be allowed to swap 2 registers with a bundle that contained `mov r0, r1` and `mov r1, r0`, depending on whether the ISA allows instructions in the same bundle to read and write the same registers.

But x86 is not like that: superscalar out-of-order execution must always preserve the illusion of running instructions one at a time in program order.  **The cardinal rule of OoO exec is: don't break single-threaded code.**

Anything that would violate this can only be done with [checking for hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)), or speculatively with rollback upon detection of mistakes.

**Footnote 2:** (continued from footnote 1)

You can fetch / decode / issue two back-to-back `inc eax` instructions, but they can't execute in the same cycle because register renaming + the OoO scheduler has to detect that the 2nd one reads the output of the first.

Comment: Ah! Now it's clear. Especially the part about running the loads ASAP but then still listening to row invalidations from the cache, that's the part I was unaware of.